# Text File DataProvider in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dataprovider, objectdataprovider

I want to read/write my entities in flat text file, and due to huge amount of data, Serlization/Deserialization is not proper solution.

Is there any data provider to work with text file data source (like csv,...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OleDB combined with the Jet-engine:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" + directoryPath 
    + "\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';"))
using (var command = new OleDbCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]", connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read())
            ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always look into a LINQ provider for the target file, obviously LINQ to XML is available.  A quick search yields other things like [LINQ to CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx), and [LINQ to Text](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/08/31/734383.aspx).

However, I don't know what support they offer with regards to what you are looking for, so you'll have to review them and not take my answer verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

though not a Text File DataProvider... check protobuf out - http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/
It is written specifically to make serialization less time+space consuming...

Its author is here on Stackoverflow - [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SQLite? It should do what you want and is pretty fast in a lot of scenarios.